# Data Structure for Two Variables (Doubles) in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am looking for the best data structure (container) which will store only two variables in Objective-C (Mac OS X or iOS app):

```
-(X) minAndMaxFinder: (NSMutableArray *)dataX {
double maxX = [[dataX valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] doubleValue];
double minX = [[dataX valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"] doubleValue];
//adding these two variables (minX and maxX) to the structure X, later these data will be used in different methods 
return X;
}
```

Should it be NSArray or something else? NSDictionary is not the obligatory solution because these two variables are not necessary connected like key-value. For example, NSMutableArray will let easily to change stored variables, but it will let as well to add more additional variables. Probably it is better to keep restriction not to let add additional variables like NSArray. As far as I know there are no vectors in Objective C unless integrating C++.

**Which solution is the most recommended in this case?**

Comment: It would help if you showed a more concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added a concrete example.

Comment: Any objection against creating an `@interface { @public id a, b; }` ?

Comment: Please pick one pair of types that you want to store (even if it's "two of anything at all"), or this quickly becomes too broad.

Comment: @user3125367 I didn't think about that possibility. A good suggestion but what if I would like to calculate them in a method?

Comment: Have you looked around for [other people's ideas about tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+tuple)?

Comment: In MRC epoch, we would just pass `id vs[2]` or `struct { id a, b; } vs`. Unfortunatelly, ARC didn't include support arrays and/or structs.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas Oops, missed that "I would like to calculate..." part. What do you mean by "calculate them in a method"? Hmm, I'm almost sure you didn't get -[valueForKeyPath:@"max.intValue"] right. What are values in your example's dataX array? NSNumbers? That then should raise exception or return two nils (casted to 0.0) at least. There is no way to "just get int" from *generic* method like valueForKeyPath: in Objective-C anyway. When we say "generic container", we're stuck with objects and boxed values everywhere, especially under ARC.

Comment: Silly question but why don't you simply pass two discrete parameters to the method (or methods)? Why the desire to complicate the issue by wrapping the two values in some strange container? Such an approach prevents good compiler checking and it adds more complicated code to encode and decode the two values.

Comment: @ user3125367, there are integer or double numbers in the dataX array. Calculations are that find the minimum and the maximum values. Basically, my point in the above example is to get these two edge values from dataX array.

Comment: @rmaddy, I considered your point, but sometimes you need just two values to go to the next methods as the parameters. Instead of writing a long methods, I just encapsulate the calculations in different methods. Moreover, sometimes it would be more better performance to access the values from some container, then processing the whole methods.

Comment: I think "tuple" is not compatible in objective-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this myself when dealing with a strange problem where this was the best solution.  It's not a typical thing to need so consider finding another way around it, however, I have a very simple class I called a Pair.  It's immutable for me but it doesn't have to be for you.

```
@interface DGCPair : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) id first;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id second;

- (instancetype)initWithFirst:(id)first 
                       second:(id)second;

@end
```

Even if your implementation file is mostly empty except for the init method this should serve your purposes.  Maybe it's a little overkill for something that could happily be done with basic data structures (or tuples if we had them) but it gets the job done.  Mine implements NSCopying for purposes of being a key in a dictionary, but, again, yours doesn't have to.

So in your case you could have:

```
-(DGCPair *)minAndMaxFinder:(NSArray *)dataX {
    double maxX = [[dataX valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] doubleValue];
    double minX = [[dataX valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"] doubleValue];

    return [[DGCPair alloc] initWithFirst:@(maxX) second:@(minX)];
}
```

You just have to make sure you remember or document which object was in which position (max in first, min in second).